# JSDoc - Is there any way to give same type for multiple variables at once?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there any way to give same type for multiple variable at once in javascript?

Usally give type like this

```
/** @type {number} */
var a = 1;
/** @type {number} */
var b = 2;
```

it is hard to define every single variable's type, so is there any way to give them same type at once?

Comment: Have you tried `var a = 1, b = 2;` ?

Comment: Last time I tried `var a = 1, b = 2;` a clean-code oriented coworker dismissed that as hard-to-read "spaghetti code", but is this valid with one common JSDoc?